# Unknown error while connecting ASValueTrackingSlider to my code

Tags: swift, xcode, uislider

Hi I am newbie in swift/xcode. Can somebody help me with the issue I am encountering. I really have no idea if what is happening on this lines here. On https://github.com/alskipp/ASValueTrackingSlider I have followed all the procedure on how to use the library. Thanks

Error 1: week may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types

Error 2: use of undeclared type ASValueTrackingSlider

[image]

[image: Error while using ASValueTrackingSlider]

Answer (score 0):

You need to bridge Objective-C code from Swift.
firstly you need to bridge yourProject-Bridging-Header.h
and import like this "#import "ASValueTrackingSlider.h"

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `import ASValueTrackingSlider`  in your view controller file ?
That might be the reason of the 2nd error